# Error when executing success post condition for Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to have add a conditional statement in the `success` block and I'm making use of the `script` block to add an `if` statement since `when` statements aren't allowed outside stage directives. Essentially, if the variable I'm checking is not true, I want the Jenkins pipeline to end and not notify about any success.

```
post {
    success {
      script { 
        if (/* checking if a variable is true */) { 
          exit 0
        } 
      }
      // proceed to notify build was successful
    }
    failure {
      // proceed to notify build failed
    }
    always {
      // delete directories
    }
}
```

But when I perform a Jenkins build, I get the following error message:

```
Error when executing success post condition:

hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 128
```

So what's the correct way to end or terminate the pipeline in the `if` statement? I know the error isn't with the way I'm notifying about success because if I delete that entire `script` block, I don't get any errors.

Comment: Why are you attempting to terminate the pipeline in the `post` section? It has already completed by that point.

Comment: You may want to consider `if (/* checking if a variable is false */) {  // proceed to notify build was successful }`.

Comment: try change to `sh 'exit 0'`

Answer (score 0):

you can use Jenkins Global variable : 'currentBuild'

you have a list on your own server :
https://yourJenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals#currentBuild

currentBuild.result == 'SUCCESS'

Personally I usually end my pipeline (scripted) with something like :

```
if (currentBuild.result == "FAILURE" || currentBuild.result == "UNSTABLE")  {
    step ([$class: 'Mailer', recipients: 'xxx@xxx.com'])
} else {
    cleanWs cleanWhenFailure: false
}
```

Hope it helps.